# JOIN three tables resulting in duplicate records

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

The following query is almost correct, except that it results in duplicate rows from the list_taxonomies table. I only need unique rows from the list_taxonomies table. I've struggled with a few solutions but can't seem to get it. I've tried LEFT OUTER and INNER joins on the items table.

Any help appreciated.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    lists.*, 
    json_agg(items ORDER BY items.id) AS _items, 
    json_agg(list_taxonomies ORDER BY list_taxonomies.type) AS taxonomy 
FROM 
    lists 
JOIN 
    list_taxonomies ON list_taxonomies.list_id = lists.id 
JOIN 
    items ON items.list_id = lists.id  
WHERE 
    lists.id = 3 
GROUP BY 
    lists.id
```

Current result:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "tincidunt pede ac urna. Ut",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing",
        "created": "2016-08-24T12:00:00.000Z",
        "updated": "2016-08-24T12:00:00.000Z",
        "owner": 9,
        "likes": 3,
        "private": 0,
        "location": "United States",
        "nsfw": 0,
        "_items": [{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "sem semper",
            "description": "sollicitudin commodo",
            "list_id": 3,
            "type": 2,
            "image": "http://fillmurray.com/",
            "list_order": 6,
            "created": "2016-08-24T05:00:00-07:00",
            "link": "http://amazon.com"
        }, {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "magna sed",
            "description": "bibendum. Donec felis",
            "list_id": 3,
            "type": 2,
            "image": "http://fillmurray.com/",
            "list_order": 1,
            "created": "2016-08-24T05:00:00-07:00",
            "link": "http://google.com"
        }],
        "taxonomy": [{
            "list_id": 3,
            "taxonomy": "Art",
            "type": 1
        }, {
            "list_id": 3,
            "taxonomy": "Art",
            "type": 1
        }, {
            "list_id": 3,
            "taxonomy": "Art",
            "type": 1
        }, {
            "list_id": 3,
            "taxonomy": "Art",
            "type": 1
        }, {
            "list_id": 3,
            "taxonomy": "Art",
            "type": 1
        }, {
            "list_id": 3,
            "taxonomy": "Art",
            "type": 1
        }, {
            "list_id": 3,
            "taxonomy": "Art",
            "type": 1
        }]
    }],
    "message": "Retrieved list 1"
}
```

Comment: try with LEFT JOIN

Comment: @McNets I've tried, same result.

Comment: should be taxonomiy inside items? Because a double left join should works.

Comment: @McNets taxonomy should be inside data, not inside the items. The structure of the returned data is correct above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When aggregating from more than one table, then aggregate before joining:

```
SELECT 
  l.*, 
  i._items, 
  lt.taxonomy 
FROM lists l
JOIN
(
  select list_id, json_agg(list_taxonomies.* order by type) AS taxonomy
  from list_taxonomies
  group by list_id
) lt ON lt.list_id = l.id 
JOIN 
(
  select list_id, json_agg(items.* order by id) AS _items
  from items
  group by list_id
) i ON i.list_id = l.id  
WHERE l.id = 3;
```

Comment: This sort of makes sense to me, but the query fails because _items isn't actually a column in items.

Comment: No it isn't. It is our alias name for the json aggregate on items. I don't see a flaw here. Maybe it needs to be `items` or ` items.*` instead of a mere `*` in `json_agg(* order by id)`? What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: I was getting `_items` does not exist. You're right though, the * by itself was causing the error. Once I changed that, it was right. Thanks!